# Remove part of the url

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I am working with Sencha Touch and PhoneGap. The code is for iOS and it's waiting for url with suffix #phonegap-external ..

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSURL *url = [request URL];
if ( ([url fragment] != NULL) && ([[url fragment] rangeOfString:@"phonegap=external"].location != NSNotFound))
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
}

return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
```

So because I haven't written any line of code in Obj-C, I need your help. Can someone edit code, so that it would open url without suffix.

EDIT:
If user opens url in app, it would open it inside webview but on occasion I would prefer that url is opened in Safari. So this code checks if url has suffix like this - http://google.com#phonegap-external and than it opens it in Safari. Only thing what bugs me, is url is not changed into http://google.com and it opens given url http://google.com/#phonegap-external. Could someone please fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it would open URL without suffix'? What does this code do/doesn't do that you wouldn't/would expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that the part of the URL that indicates whether it's to be opened inline or externally (i. e. the `#phonegap-external` string) is always the last one in the URL, then you can try removing this suffix by writing something like as follows:

```
NSString *orig = [url absoluteString];
size_t frLen = [@"phonegap-external" length];
NSString *stripped = [orig substringToIndex:orig.length - frLen];
NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stripped];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:newURL];
```